# if statement won't detect that list is NOT empty | TKINTER LABEL

Tags: python, list, tkinter, label

I have a publicly declared an empty list. After pressing button it is appended with a LABEL. `<tkinter.Label object .!label>`

IF statement does something if length of the list is 0 and does something differently when length is NOT 0.

Program detects the first length of 0 and acts accordingly, but the second time IT STILL ACTS LIKE THE LIST WOULD BE OF LENGTH 0. And then the third time it actually detects that the list is not empty. Any idea where is the problem?

Tried these methods:

```
if len(labels) == 0

if not labels
```

In my first IF I want to set label `pady = 50` and after that all the next label should be `pady = 5` but on second time it still react as if list would be empty. Only makes `pady = 5` in the third go

Whole code :

```
import requests
from tkinter import *


master = Tk()
master.title('APPLICATION')
master.geometry("1200x750")


labels = []



def ok():
    


    if  len(labels) == 0:
        my_label = Label(text="001")
        my_label.pack(pady=50, side=TOP, anchor=NW)
    else:
        my_label = Label(text="001")
        my_label.pack(pady=5, side=TOP, anchor=NW)

    print(len(labels))


    labels.append(my_label)

    print(labels)

OKbutton = Button(master, text="OK", command=ok)
OKbutton.pack(pady=20, padx=20)
OKbutton.config(height=1, width=8)
OKbutton.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.05, anchor=N)


mainloop()
```

Output = [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiCHm.png)

Comment: Can you post the code or an example?

Comment: please add the code and all the relevant details

Comment: This is not enough. Can you post your 'if else' sequence?

Comment: Show the way you init and change the labels value please. We need a full working example here so we can help, so spot the problem.

Comment: Please provide a working [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `pady=50` means 50 pixels on the top and same on the bottom of the widget as well. So if you want the padding to just be on the top of the widget, then use a `tuple` to specify pixels, like:

```
pady=(50,0) # 50 on top, 0 on bottom
```

So your code would be like:

```
if len(labels) == 0:
    my_label = Label(text="001")
    my_label.pack(pady=(50,0), side=TOP, anchor=NW) # 50px top, nothing on bottom
```